# Как сделать в WordPress теме Basic или вообще, посадочную страницу уникальную на каждой странице?

Tags: wordpress

Хочу разместить текст определенный над footer. Но, разместив там, он продублировался на всех страницах! Как сделать так, чтобы я мог из админки публиковать записи в эту область над футером? В других cms это уже с коробки реализовано, обычно seo текст на страницах, вот и мне нужно сделать посадочное место на странице для сео текста, но чтобы я его заполнять мог ручками для каждой страницы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Есть три пути, через functions.php и добавление СВОЕГО мета поля и привязка содержимого через hook, либо через плагин и hook, либо подбором темы, где подобное реализовано.

Comment: Какая тема? У разных тем, есть разные области и свои хуки.

Comment: Тема "Basic" - https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/basic/, она стандартная, я писал в заголовке. Через хук не понимаю как, но надеюсь вы поняли о чем я, мне нужна просто маленькая область над футером, обычный див, так сказать, но чтобы он был уникальный на каждой странице, а лучше, дабы я мог его редактировать. Я представлял это - как новую запись добавлять и туда бы выводился этот текст. Такая возможность нужна мне для продвижения страницы по некоторым запросам.

Comment: Если Мы говорим об одной и той же теме, то в ней в файле футер есть 2 хука. **basic_before_footer** перед футером и **basic_before_footer_menu** внутри футера. Кстати, почему тебе не использовать краткое описание для вывода в эту область, вместо того, что бы ещё одно место поле делать? Если не планируешь, использовать (краткое описание) для стандартного использования, то это гуд решение. Отсигналь, краткое описание тебе надо или нет?

Comment: У тебя уже сделана child тема для BASIC? Править саму тему - не верно.

Comment: Ещё вопрос: ты на всех страницах хочешь выводить блок или только в постах или только в записях? Просто есть и архивы и тэги и категории... Надо учитывать и понимать где, что должно быть. И да, добавлять поле в разных местах добавляется различно (если без плагина ACF)

Comment: Я хочу выводить это лишь в страницах - категории(в самой странице категории и потом в каждой категории), новые записи, популярные, просматриваемые и тд, в записях я выводить не хочу - только на страницах главных.

Comment: По поводу краткого описания это же вроде дескрипшин просто, нет?

Comment: Ещё раз, уточню. Разговор о **категориях**, это товары или **записи**? Просто **категории** чаще имеются в виду товарные категории? Это важно, что бы написать корректное решение. В любом случае, я бы рекомендовал установить ACF, это быстро установить и проще потом настроить.

Comment: Категории записей, например, история какая - юмор, триллер, фантастика и тд.

Comment: Смотри ниже ответ с видео. Имя seo_field - жёстко привязано к выводу. Ошибёшься в написании, ничего не выведет.

Answer (score 2):

> мне нужно сделать посадочное место на странице для сео текста, но
> чтобы я его заполнять мог ручками для каждой страницы.

Для этого используются [произвольные поля](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F).

А чтобы их вывести нужно сперва сделать [дочернюю тему](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B) и в ней в footer.php (или в другой шаблон) вставить вывод этого ПП.

Дочернюю тему лучше сделать с помощью плагина [CTC](https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/), который потом можно удалить.
А для удобства работы с ПП тоже лучше использовать [какой-нибудь плагин](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/custom+fields/). Только нужно учесть что некоторые плагины используют не стандартные, а свои функции для работы с ПП. Поэтому потребуется изучение работы с плагином.

Comment: По моему, это для данного человека не решение. Слишком много надо вникать, читать и тестировать.

Comment: Скорее всего да, слишком сложно)

Comment: @iFlyZed это самое простое. И это основы кастомизации. А на изучение этой "сложности" и реализации потребуется не больше часа времени.

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем случае если без плагинов, то могу указать на статью

> https://misha.agency/wordpress/metadannyie-v-taksonomiyah.html

Но тут надо обладать базовыми знаниями и понимать, что и для чего.

Если таковых нет, самый простой способ - установить **ACF (Advanced Custom Fields)** и быстро добавить необходимое туда, куда надо. После установки плагина появится в левом меню админки пункт "Произвольные поля", либо "Группы полей" заходим. Например, что бы добавить к категориям поле надо сделать следующее.
Видео на яндекс диске -> [ссылка на папку с файлами](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/K7b_IcUvG0hLHQ)

В примере я ограничил длину поля, только для того, что бы показать, что есть такая возможность (это можно не делать).
Кроме того, Вы можете выбрать не "текст" и не "область текста", а "Редактор текста", но **данный пример под "область текста"**.
Это значит, что я делаю первичное форматирование - Заменяет двойной перенос строки на HTML конструкцию `<p>...</p>`, а одинарный на `<br>`, с возможностью вывода шорткода.

Код вставить в файл finctions.php (вашей темы). **ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО** создать дочернюю тему, поскольку, если делать в самой теме, то все Ваши шаманства будут затёрты с первым же обновлением темы.
Не надо думать, что это не произойдёт... Обязательно обновитесь и обязательно всё потеряете.

```
add_action( 'basic_before_footer', 'seo_function' );
function seo_function() {
    global $wp_query;
    $object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    $seo_term = get_field('seo_field', $object);

    if($seo_term){
        echo '<div id="main" class="maxwidth clearfix">'; // Стили с отступом
        $seo_term = wpautop( $seo_term ); // Авто подмена
        echo do_shortcode( $seo_term ); // Выполнить шорткоды
        echo '</div>';
    }else{
        //Ничего нет, ничего и не выводим
    }
}
```

01.09.2021 К вопросу, о том, как добавить эту настройку к главной или посту/странице
И так, [ссылка на папку с картинками](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/YnlLkFg2-RrgXQ)

1. В файле `Главная - настройка.jpg` -> где посмотреть и выбрать главную.
2. `Добавление 1.jpg` - нажимаем редактировать уже созданную группу
3. `Добавление 2.jpg` - добавляем новую группу условия для поля черезе условие **ИЛИ**
4. `Добавление 3.jpg` - добавляем правило через тип записи (поле будет появляться во всех записях или страницах)
5. `Добавление 4.jpg` - добавляем правило **конкретной записи**
6. `Добавление 5.jpg` - добавляем правило **конкретной странице**

Смотришь, выбираешь, развлекаешься.
Для того, что бы выводить это поле на страницах, добавь к тому что есть:

```
add_action( 'basic_after_page_comments_area', 'seo_function' );
```

после чего получиться:

```
add_action( 'basic_before_footer', 'seo_function' );
add_action( 'basic_after_page_comments_area', 'seo_function' );
function seo_function() {
... код ...
}
```

У меня работает. Проверил. Если не будет работать, надо смотреть что не так сделано / настроено.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129445/discussion-on-answer-by-sergio----wordpress--basic---).